# Binary logistic regression with a dichotomous predictor

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm getting puzzled by a binary logistic regression in R with (obviously) a dichotomous outcome variable (coded 0 and 1) and a dichotomous predictor variable (coded 0 and 1). A contingency table suggests the outcome is a very good predictor, but it's not coming out as significant in my logistic regression. I found the same effect with a dummy problem, so I wonder if somebody can help me spot the problem here when I use a 'perfect' predictor?

```
outcome <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1)
predictor <- outcome
model <- glm(outcome ~ predictor, family = binomial)
summary(model)

Call:
glm(formula = outcome ~ predictor, family = binomial)

Deviance Residuals: 
            Min               1Q           Median               3Q              
   Max  
-0.000006547293  -0.000006547293  -0.000006547293   0.000006547293   0.000006547293  

Coefficients:
           Estimate  Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   -24.56607 53484.89343 -0.00046  0.99963
predictor      49.13214 79330.94390  0.00062  0.99951

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 15.15820324648649020  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  0.00000000047153748  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 4

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 23
```

My question is why "predictor" comes out with p = .999 rather than something very small, given that it should perfectly predict the outcome here. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The output is the same if I change the main command to outcome ~ as.factor(predictor)